# unexpected token , using map

Tags: javascript

```
let discounts = [...this.state.discounts];
discounts = [3,5,7,30].map(day, e => (
       day,
       content: this.state[`discount_${day}`]
))
```

What's wrong with line 4? I got:

> unexpected token at this.state

Comment: sounds like your spread operator isnt being transpiled correctly. To test you are transpiling your code correctly assign a new var to a spread array and see if you gett the error again

Comment: @MayankShukla I just want to know what's wrong with this code, there's no output.

Comment: @JoeLloyd there's no different using var or let

Comment: @PriyeshKumar of course I can't see anything coz I've error in line 4.

Comment: @AlanJenshen of course there is. but that's not what im telling you to do. test your spread operator is working in isolation

Comment: if you want to return an object, you need to use `,` and `{}`, like this: `({
                day,
                content: this.state[`discount_${day}`]
       } )` but your ques is not clear so mention everything properly.

Comment: @MayankShukla I got day is not defined error. Why?

Comment: @Alan any clue? http://i.imgur.com/0xFeHsc.png

Comment: @AlanJenshen you need to use `()` like : `(day,e) => ({})`

Comment: `map` is not ES6. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @user633183 What a snobbish, elitist attitude. Rude and unhelpful. What's even more sad is your comment have 3 votes.

Comment: Amir, the community considers questions like this off-topic. It's not my personal opinion...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do? Bit difficult to know without further information of what you are trying to achieve.

```
discounts = [3,5,7,30].map((day, e) => ({
   day,
   content: this.state[`discount_${day}`]
}))
```

Comment: put a bracket around the args (day,e)=>

Comment: is the last `(` needed?

Comment: yes. you need it as it makes this an implied return. `(day, e) => ()` will return whatever is in the second brackets, `(day, e) => {}` will not return anything (unless you add a return statement). So when you do `(day, e) => ({})` it is the same as saying `(day, e) => { return {} }`

Comment: did this fix your problem?